# Ignore Field used in HAVING clause on SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, having-clause

I have the following query.

```
SELECT parent.id AS 'id', parent.CA_NAME as 'name', node.level AS 'level', midpoint.level AS 'midpointlevel', SUM(ad.id IS NOT NULL) AS 'count'
FROM
category AS parent,
category AS midpoint,
category AS node
LEFT JOIN ad ON ad.id=node.id
AND ad.status='A'
WHERE (node.`LEFT` BETWEEN parent.`LEFT` AND parent.`RIGHT`)
AND (node.`LEFT` BETWEEN midpoint.`LEFT` AND midpoint.`RIGHT`)
AND midpoint.id='1'
GROUP BY parent.id
HAVING IF(midpoint.level=0, node.level < 2, node.level > 0)
ORDER BY parent.id
```

I don't want to select the `midpoint.level AS 'midpointlevel'` part but if I remove it the having clause gives an error mentioning : Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'midpoint.level' in 'having clause'. Can anyone help me to remove the unwanted select section.

Comment: This is a really good question and I am looking forward to reading an adequate answer.

Comment: There are multiple possible `midpoint.level` values in each group.  Which do you want to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a simple subquery:

```
SELECT id, 
       name,
       -- midpointlevel,  <-- commented out, since we don't need this column 
       level, 
       count
FROM (
  SELECT parent.id AS 'id', parent.CA_NAME as 'name', node.level AS 'level',  midpoint.level AS 'midpointlevel', SUM(ad.id IS NOT NULL) AS 'count'
  FROM
  category AS parent,
  category AS midpoint,
  category AS node
  LEFT JOIN ad ON ad.id=node.id
  AND ad.status='A'
  WHERE (node.`LEFT` BETWEEN parent.`LEFT` AND parent.`RIGHT`)
  AND (node.`LEFT` BETWEEN midpoint.`LEFT` AND midpoint.`RIGHT`)
  AND midpoint.id='1'
  GROUP BY parent.id
  HAVING IF(midpoint.level=0, node.level < 2, node.level > 0)
  ORDER BY parent.id
) subquery
```

Comment: thanks this is working.. But do you think there will be a performance impact due to the subquery.

Comment: No, in this case (straight SELECT form subquery, without additional WHERE clasue), running time will be exactly the same as for oryginal query.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name
HAVING aggregate_function(column_name) operator value;

Refer above syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it from the select if you add it to the GROUP BY.  Not familiar with HAVING IF.  Try this:

```
GROUP BY parent.id,midpoint.level
HAVING (midpoint.level=0 AND node.level < 2 AND node.level > 0)
ORDER BY parent.id
```